# Vaadin 7 to 8 upgrade widgetset

Tags: vaadin7, vaadin8

We want to upg. 7 to 8. vaadin application.
I tried to migrate the application vaadin framework migration tool etc.
Also, we have custom widgetset and I followed the instructions https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/15031831/vaadin-8-compatibility-widgetset-implementation-missing-for-v7-component

So, although our custom wigdetset gwt xml contains
"inherits name="com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet"

Widgetset 'XXXXXXWidgetset' does not contain an implementation for com.vaadin.v7.ui.TextField. Check the connector's @Connect mapping, the widgetset's GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to

Please help me. Thanks.

----pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-client</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-charts</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `com.vaadin.v7.ui.TextField` will require that you have the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-client</artifactId>
    <version>8.14.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I shared not all of my pom.xml. Just belonging to vaadin dep. I already have it.

Comment: @Tatus btw that was the version of vaadin <vaadin.version>8.3.3</vaadin.version> .

Comment: @HasanBirol I'd expect that no explicit version is needed, as it would also come
from the BOM - but why are using scope=provided?